# Stata: Selecting cases with non-integer numbers

Tags: stata

What am I doing wrong with the following? It's being read in as a float by default. Why isn't the `count` returning 1?

```
clear
input stake
0.01
end
count if stake == 0.01
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with Stata's numerical precision. By default you're storing `stake` as a single precision `float`. Try `input double stake` to input `stake` to higher, `double` precision. Or `count if stake == float(0.01)` to incorporate this precision into your test.

The Stata blog had a series of posts on this topic a few years ago. More [here](http://blog.stata.com/2011/06/17/precision-yet-again-part-i/).